# Only run code if git tag exists for current commit in BASH

Tags: bash, git

I want to only run a piece of bash code if a git tag exists for the current commit.

The command `git describe --exact-match` gives throws an error if there is no git tag for the current commit which is a good start so I'm trying to combine that into an if statement in bash:

```
if $(git describe --exact-match);  then
    TAG="$(git describe --exact-match)"
    echo "TAG=$TAG"
  else
    echo "no tag"
fi
```

The above code works when there is no tag for the current commit but if there is a tag then it fails.

Comment: Just remove the `$(` and `)`. `if <command>` checks whether `<command>` exited 0.

Comment: @Biffen thanks that works do you want to post that as the answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: I’d kinda rather close this as a typo. Or a duplicate; I’m fairly sure there is one. **edit** There we are!